# In Operator in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

[image]

this is my collection structure injury contain injury data i have two injuryid so i jst want those injuries 
for example i have  2 ids(538d9e7ed173e5202a000065,538f21868a5fc5e01f000065) then i have to get only 1st two array i user IN operator bt still get all 3 array..i tried below query

```
        db.users.find(
                   {"injury._id":{$in:[ObjectId("538d9e7ed173e5202a000065"),
                                       ObjectId("538f21868a5fc5e01f000065")]}
                   })
```

using that i got all 3 array

Comment: Yes. It's an array and this does not filter the array. You also have similar questions that you have asked before and have been given answers as to how to do this but you have not clearly presented your data on any of them and again you have done the same by providing a screenshot and not the actual data. I suggest you go back to your previous questions and clarify your data so you can actually be led through how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to understand here is that your query is meant to filter "documents" and does not filter elements of the array "within" a document. In order to actually filter the array contents for more than a single match you need to use the aggregation framework:

```js
db.users.aggregate([
    // Matches the "documents" containing those elements in the array
    { "$match": {
        "injury._id":{
            "$in": [
                ObjectId("538d9e7ed173e5202a000065"),
                ObjectId("538f21868a5fc5e01f000065")
            ]
        }
    }},

    // Unwind the array to de-normalize as documents
    { "$unwind": "$injury" },

    // Match the array members
    { "$match": {
        "injury._id":{
            "$in": [
                ObjectId("538d9e7ed173e5202a000065"),
                ObjectId("538f21868a5fc5e01f000065")
            ]
        }
    }},

    // Group back as an array
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "injury": { "$push": "$injury" }
    }}

])
```

Under MongoDB 2.6 and greater you can utilize [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to filter the array:

```js
db.users.aggregate([
    // Matches the "documents" containing those elements in the array
    { "$match": {
        "injury._id":{
            "$in": [
                ObjectId("538d9e7ed173e5202a000065"),
                ObjectId("538f21868a5fc5e01f000065")
            ]
        }
    }},

    // Project with $map to filter
    { "$project": {
        "injury": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$injury",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": {
                        "$cond": [
                        {
                            "$or": [
                                    { "$eq": [ 
                                        "$$el._id"
                                        ObjectId("538d9e7ed173e5202a000065")
                                    ]},
                                    { "$eq": [ 
                                        "$$el._id"
                                        ObjectId("538f21868a5fc5e01f000065")
                                    ]}
                                ]
                            },
                            "$$el",
                            false
                        ]
                    }
                }}, 
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }}

])
```

Comment: @MaTya I'm sure it does. Generally good to "accept" the answers that help you. Helps people know the solution worked and helps those who help you. And do not forget the other questions that you have left open as well.